# My JavaScript file blocked as unsecured file

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, digital-ocean

I made a multiplayer checkers game website a while back and recently hosted it publicly. Everything seemed to work fine when I tested it myself and got other people within my friend groups.

However, I recently posted the site to Dream In Code, and got a few people telling me that it simply wasn't working. One user suggested that the app.js file was being blocked by their browsers.

I'm a little confused as to why this would happen, and I'm interested in finding out how widespread this issue is.

The URL is www.multiplayercheckers.co.uk.

Could anyone check it out and see if they can get past the initial page? I'd really appreciate it. I'm not sure where else to try.

Comment: I'm not having that issue. Are those users using an adblocker?

Comment: I'm using Adblock Plus and it works fine for me

Comment: Without being able to reproduce the problem, we can't resolve it. You'll need to collect more information from your users, before we can help.

Comment: It shouldn't necessarily be causing an issue, but I noticed all of your libraries are being served over https while the page itself and app.js are using http. 

Perhaps some users are using very aggressive browser security settings which won't let them run anything coming from an unsecured source?